# Creating a Generic Struct Indexed by a Generic NewType

Tags: generics, struct, rust, newtype

I'd like to create a generic struct that uses a generic newtype to index. Ideally it would look something like this:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct Foo<I, T> {
    bar: Vec<T>,
    _marker: PhantomData<I>,
}

impl <I, T> Foo<I, T> {
    fn new(v: Vec<T>) -> Foo<I, T> {
        Foo {
            bar: v,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
    fn get(&self, index: &I) -> &T {
        // let index: usize = index.0; // I want to use this line.
        let index = 0; // This line is incorrect, but compiles.
        &self.bar[index]
    }
}
```

The generic newtype is guaranteed to be `usize`, like this:

```
pub struct Baz(pub usize);
pub struct Qux(pub usize);
```

This compiles and correctly enforces type checking.

```
fn main() {
    let index_b = Baz(1);
    let index_q = Qux(1);
    let data: Foo<Baz, i32> = Foo::new(vec![1,2,3]);
    assert_eq!(*data.get(&index_b), 2);

    // Type Checking Violation - Does not compile.
    // assert_eq!(*data.get(&index_q), 2);
}
```

However notice that the `get()` function is incorrect. How do you tell the compiler that `I` is a usize so the `get()` function will be correct?

Comment: You have many such newtypes and you want `Foo` to treat them all the same? That seems to be rather against the spirit of a newtype.

Comment: @trentcl I apologize for being unclear. I included an example of how this pattern enforces type checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to use some kind of trait. There's no existing constraint to verify that an `I` is actually a `SomeType(T)` to know that `index.0` is valid.

My immediate thought would be to implement `Into` on your newtype:

```
#[derive(Copy, Clone)]
pub struct Baz(pub usize);

impl Into<usize> for Baz {
    fn into(self) -> usize {
        self.0
    }
}
```

And you would pass `index` by value into `get`:

```
fn get(&self, index: I) -> &T
where
    I: Into<usize>
{
    &self.bar[index.into()]
}
```

Other options would be `Deref` or `AsRef` or it may make sense to make your own `FooIndex` trait.

---

For `AsRef`:

```
fn get(&self, index: &I) -> &T
where
    I: AsRef<usize>
{
    &self.bar[*index.as_ref()]
}
```

And `Deref`:

```
fn get(&self, index: &I) -> &T
where
    I: Deref<Target=usize>
{
    &self.bar[**index]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Could you put `#[derive(Copy, Clone)]` above the `Baz` definition so I can mark it correct?
Also, if I took the `Deref` or `AsRef` approach what would the `where` signatures inside of  `impl <I, T> Foo<I, T>` look like?

Comment: @HiDefender I updated the answer. While not required `Copy` definitely makes it easier to use.